# Define custom value deserializer on KafkaListener

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In my main `application.properties`, I have:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

This is all working fine, and the values are deserialized to a `String` as expected.

Now, in my integration tests, I want to introduce another `KafkaListener` (that is, a second listener, I do not want to override the behavior of the one in my main application!), but this time with another value deserializer (to a byte array). Is this possible, without having to introduce a custom `ListenerContainerFactory` for this listener?

I tried the following, but without success:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = ..., properties = "value-deserializer:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer")
public void receiveKafkaRecords(final ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record) {
    ...
}
```

I am getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B
```

This means that the ad-hoc value deserializer as defined on the `KafkaListener` in the integration test is not used.

I am currently using spring-kafka 2.5.8.

Comment: Typo? [The correct Consumer client property is `value.deserializer`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs)

Comment: Right, indeed! I was confused between `value.deserializer` in the consumer properties, but `value-deserializer` in the application properties. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`properties` needs to be a list of strings, and can reference constants

```
@KafkaListener(topics = ..., properties = {
  ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG + "=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer"
})
public void receiveKafkaRecords(final ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record) {
    ...
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-properties

This will correctly use `value.deserializer` as the key (dot, not hyphen)

Or in your integration test, you can load a different property file.